# Replace data from dataframe using other threshold table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, threshold

I have 2 dataframes, the first has data for many months, and the second has threshold values (minimum and maximum, different for every month). Now I want to replace any values outside the thresholds with NA.

The structure of the dataframes is as follows:
Data has columns with names "month", "a", "b" and "c". Thresholds has "month", "a.min", "a.max", "b.min" and "b.max".

```
thresholds <- structure(list(month = 1:3, a.min = c(1L, 2L, 0L), a.max = c(9L, 8L, 3L), b.min = c(50L, 60L, 30L), b.max = c(70L, 75L, 90L)), .Names = c("month", "a.min", "a.max", "b.min", "b.max"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
df <- structure(list(a = c(3.693, 0.534, 3.068, 2.633, 3.047, 3.072, 3.278, 3.533, 3.406, 2.893, 2.722, 0.513, 1.994, 1.743, 1.958, 2.03, 2.222, 2.207, 2.393, 2.731, 15.464, 4.065, 3.458, 3.142, 2.705, 17.285, 1.794, 2.139, 2.455, 2.83, 3.008, 3.358, 3.663, 2.936, 2.636, 2.42, 3.403, 2.83, 2.74, 3.119, 2.376, 3.285, 3.267, 2.966, 3.675, 2.803, 3.097, 3.381, 2.774, 3.335, 3.857, 2.854, 3.093, 2.368, 2.8, 2.643, 3.047, 2.559, 2.119, 1.712, 1.614, 1.474, 1.82, 2.147, 2.405, 2.543, 2.374, 2.962, 3.375, 3.002, 2.785, 2.643, 2.304, 2.052, 2.116, 2.203, 2.574, 2.537, 2.306, 1.316, 2.164, 1.855, 1.501, 1.331, 1.417, 1.158, 0.792, 0.183, 0.567, 1.406, 0.975, 1.48, 0.473, 0.689, 0.046, 0.498, 1.847, 2.079, 2.454, 3.372), b = c(72.26, 77.25, 72.3, 75.79, 72.98, 83.6, 79.16, 80.9, 80.2, 80.2, 73.33, 72, 63.7, 47.14, 30.86, 47.2, 56.69, 46.94, 56.74, 50.95, 65.32, 71.82, 67.36, 65.04, 60, 53.26, 39.08, 46.73, 57.16, 80.9, 63.45, 52.17, 56.59, 54.27, 54.87, 43.51, 59.04, 50.24, 40.62, 46.33, 43.49, 55.31, 55.21, 55.76, 60.77, 49.29, 45.27, 34.23, 51.32, 81.9, 82.6, 79.03, 69.54, 70.3, 77.78, 96.4, 95.9, 93.2, 101.9, 93.2, 93, 93.8, 79.67, 63.16, 59.23, 61.44, 48.7, 60.45, 69.92, 69.54, 67.86, 73.45, 95.6, 87.8, 78.91, 71.7, 84.1, 93.4, 89.5, 88.5, 88.2, 88.2, 98.7, 117.9, 141, 157.2, 155.8, 149.6, 95.2, 91.1, 113.4, 66.98, 39.31, 41.21, 255.8, 247.5, 248.2, 251, 255.1, 250.4),c = c(384.399, 388.0435, 391.158, 394.1089, 396.2393, 397.7653,405.9039, 413.3497, 413.8737, 412.4252,401.0619, 395.5369,393.344, 390.2218, 380.8314, 370.9777, 365.3473, 365.9187,362.2083, 368.0958, 369.2954, 369.1633, 367.9333, 364.1945,359.7283, 357.4523,357.9721, 356.7934, 355.4262, 358.4297,357.7325, 362.7329, 365.4261, 363.8837,362.5658, 363.5668,369.6555, 366.5757, 360.5511, 360.7731, 360.5672, 363.6154,367.0974, 363.4489, 373.0476, 379.0865, 382.3346, 386.7982,394.0651, 398.8354,398.6193, 401.3643, 401.9453, 405.3331,417.1013, 425.4676, 423.6085, 421.9701,410.8265, 404.4327,401.7433, 397.9707, 389.2195, 379.0507, 371.2411, 370.1493,365.7072, 367.7261, 370.8189, 368.1045, 365.2104, 366.9838,370.7158, 371.3767,370.1482, 367.5164, 365.9738, 367.5455,368.9097, 366.8438, 361.4221, 363.1824,364.9451, 362.9793,364.1421, 360.9064, 359.4199, 358.8081, 354.5116, 352.878,351.8854, 354.0268, 364.0585, 368.6769, 382.3471, 385.0213,385.3837, 390.994, 388.8896, 386.261), month = c(1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c","month"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

I manually created some expected output. Basically, for month 1, the limits a.min and a.max are applied to column a. Then, for month 2, the next limits are applied. For column b, the limits b.min and b.max are applied:

```
outcome <- structure(list(month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), a = c(3.693, NA,3.68, 2.633, 3.47, 3.72, 3.278, 3.533, 3.46, 2.893, 2.722, NA,1.994, 1.743, 1.958, 2.3, 2.222, 2.27, 2.393, 2.731, NA, 4.65,3.458, 3.142, 2.75, NA,1.794, 2.139, 2.455, 2.83, 3.8, 3.358,3.663, 2.936, 2.636, 2.42, 3.43, 2.83, 2.74, 3.119, 2.376, 3.285,3.267, 2.966, 3.675, 2.83, 3.97, 3.381, 2.774, 3.335, 3.857,2.854, 3.93, 2.368, 2.8, 2.643, 3.47, 2.559, 2.119, NA, NA, NA,NA, 2.147, 2.45, 2.543, 2.374, 2.962, 3.375, 3.2, 2.785, 2.643,2.34, 2.52, 2.116, 2.23, 2.574, 2.537, 2.36, NA, 2.164, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.46, 0.975, 1.48, 0.473, 0.689, 0.46,0.498, 1.847, 2.79, 2.454, NA), b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 63.7, NA, NA, NA, 56.69, NA, 56.74, 5.95,65.32, NA, 67.36, 65.4, 6, 53.26, NA, NA, 57.16, NA, 63.45, 52.17,56.59, 54.27, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.77, NA,NA,NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, 69.54, 7.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, 63.16, NA, 61.44, NA, 6.45, 69.92, 69.54, 67.86, 73.45, NA, NA, NA, 71.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 66.98, 39.31, 41.21, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),     c = c(384.399, 388.435, 391.158, 394.189, 396.2393, 397.7653,45.939,413.3497, 413.8737, 412.4252, 41.619, 395.5369, 393.344,39.2218, 38.8314, 37.9777, 365.3473, 365.9187, 362.283, 368.958,369.2954, 369.1633, 367.9333, 364.1945, 359.7283,357.4523,357.9721,356.7934,355.4262,358.4297,357.7325,362.7329,365.4261, 363.8837, 362.5658, 363.5668, 369.6555, 366.5757,36.5511, 36.7731, 36.5672, 363.6154, 367.974, 363.4489, 373.476,379.865, 382.3346, 386.7982, 394.651, 398.8354, 398.6193,41.3643, 41.9453, 45.3331, 417.113, 425.4676, 423.685, 421.971,41.8265, 44.4327, 41.7433, 397.977, 389.2195, 379.57, 371.2411,37.1493, 365.772, 367.7261, 7.8189,368.145,365.214,366.9838,37.7158, 371.3767, 37.1482, 367.5164, 365.9738, 367.5455,368.997, 366.8438, 361.4221, 363.1824, 364.9451, 362.9793,364.1421, 36.964, 359.4199, 358.881, 354.5116, 352.878, 351.8854, 354.268, 364.585, 368.6769, 382.3471, 385.213, 385.3837, 39.994, 388.8896, 386.261)), .Names = c("month", "a", "b","c"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now my question: How can I do this in R??? And how can I do it on dataframes with dozens of columns?

Comment: What do you mean "apply limit"?

Comment: I mean to use the thresholds, and anything outside of those should become NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base R:

```
# use merge to pull in the thresholds
outcome <- merge(df, thresholds, all.x=TRUE, by="month")

# define the columns to look at, that require a .min, .max column
threshold_cols <- c("a", "b")

# loop and update
for(i in threshold_cols){
  # create a condition vector to highlight ones out of the range
  con <- outcome[[i]] < outcome[[sprintf("%s.min", i)]] |
    outcome[[i]] > outcome[[sprintf("%s.max", i)]]
  # force these as NA
  outcome[[i]][con] <- NA
}
```

Is this ok? Jonny

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` you could do something like this

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  left_join(thresholds) %>% 
  mutate(a=ifelse(a > a.min & a < a.max, a, NA),
         b=ifelse(b > b.min & b < b.max, b, NA)) %>% 
  select(month, a, b, c)

df2
    month     a     b        c
1       1 3.693    NA 384.3990
2       1    NA    NA 388.0435
3       1 3.068    NA 391.1580
4       1 2.633    NA 394.1089
5       1 3.047    NA 396.2393
6       1 3.072    NA 397.7653
7       1 3.278    NA 405.9039
...
```

Comment: This is nice, but if there are more columns, then every column has to be dealt with in a new line. And I want to run this on a huge dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this can be achieved by a sequence of *non-equi update joins*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[setDT(thresholds), on = .(month, a < a.min), a := NA][
  thresholds, on = .(month, a > a.max), a := NA][
    thresholds, on = .(month, b < b.min), b := NA][
      thresholds, on = .(month, b > b.max), b := NA][]
```

> ```
>          a     b        c month
>   1: 3.693    NA 384.3990     1
>   2:    NA    NA 388.0435     1
>   3: 3.068    NA 391.1580     1
>   4: 2.633    NA 394.1089     1
>   5: 3.047    NA 396.2393     1
>   6: 3.072    NA 397.7653     1
>   7: 3.278    NA 405.9039     1
>   8: 3.533    NA 413.3497     1
>   9: 3.406    NA 413.8737     1
>  10: 2.893    NA 412.4252     1
>  11: 2.722    NA 401.0619     1
>  12:    NA    NA 395.5369     1
>  13: 1.994 63.70 393.3440     1
>  14: 1.743    NA 390.2218     1
>  15: 1.958    NA 380.8314     1
>  16: 2.030    NA 370.9777     1
>  17: 2.222 56.69 365.3473     1
>  18: 2.207    NA 365.9187     1
>  19: 2.393 56.74 362.2083     1
>  20: 2.731 50.95 368.0958     1
>  21:    NA 65.32 369.2954     1
>  22: 4.065    NA 369.1633     1
>  23: 3.458 67.36 367.9333     1
>  24: 3.142 65.04 364.1945     1
>  25: 2.705 60.00 359.7283     1
>  26:    NA 53.26 357.4523     1
>  27: 1.794    NA 357.9721     1
>  28: 2.139    NA 356.7934     1
>  29: 2.455 57.16 355.4262     1
>  30: 2.830    NA 358.4297     1
>  31: 3.008 63.45 357.7325     1
>  32: 3.358 52.17 362.7329     1
>  33: 3.663 56.59 365.4261     1
>  34: 2.936 54.27 363.8837     1
>  35: 2.636    NA 362.5658     2
>  36: 2.420    NA 363.5668     2
>  37: 3.403    NA 369.6555     2
>  38: 2.830    NA 366.5757     2
>  39: 2.740    NA 360.5511     2
>  40: 3.119    NA 360.7731     2
>  41: 2.376    NA 360.5672     2
>  42: 3.285    NA 363.6154     2
>  43: 3.267    NA 367.0974     2
>  44: 2.966    NA 363.4489     2
>  45: 3.675 60.77 373.0476     2
>  46: 2.803    NA 379.0865     2
>  47: 3.097    NA 382.3346     2
>  48: 3.381    NA 386.7982     2
>  49: 2.774    NA 394.0651     2
>  50: 3.335    NA 398.8354     2
>  51: 3.857    NA 398.6193     2
>  52: 2.854    NA 401.3643     2
>  53: 3.093 69.54 401.9453     2
>  54: 2.368 70.30 405.3331     2
>  55: 2.800    NA 417.1013     2
>  56: 2.643    NA 425.4676     2
>  57: 3.047    NA 423.6085     2
>  58: 2.559    NA 421.9701     2
>  59: 2.119    NA 410.8265     2
>  60:    NA    NA 404.4327     2
>  61:    NA    NA 401.7433     2
>  62:    NA    NA 397.9707     2
>  63:    NA    NA 389.2195     2
>  64: 2.147 63.16 379.0507     2
>  65: 2.405    NA 371.2411     2
>  66: 2.543 61.44 370.1493     2
>  67: 2.374    NA 365.7072     2
>  68: 2.962 60.45 367.7261     2
>  69: 3.375 69.92 370.8189     2
>  70: 3.002 69.54 368.1045     2
>  71: 2.785 67.86 365.2104     2
>  72: 2.643 73.45 366.9838     2
>  73: 2.304    NA 370.7158     2
>  74: 2.052    NA 371.3767     2
>  75: 2.116    NA 370.1482     2
>  76: 2.203 71.70 367.5164     2
>  77: 2.574    NA 365.9738     2
>  78: 2.537    NA 367.5455     2
>  79: 2.306    NA 368.9097     2
>  80:    NA    NA 366.8438     2
>  81: 2.164    NA 361.4221     2
>  82:    NA    NA 363.1824     2
>  83:    NA    NA 364.9451     2
>  84:    NA    NA 362.9793     2
>  85:    NA    NA 364.1421     2
>  86:    NA    NA 360.9064     2
>  87:    NA    NA 359.4199     2
>  88:    NA    NA 358.8081     2
>  89:    NA    NA 354.5116     2
>  90: 1.406    NA 352.8780     3
>  91: 0.975    NA 351.8854     3
>  92: 1.480 66.98 354.0268     3
>  93: 0.473 39.31 364.0585     3
>  94: 0.689 41.21 368.6769     3
>  95: 0.046    NA 382.3471     3
>  96: 0.498    NA 385.0213     3
>  97: 1.847    NA 385.3837     3
>  98: 2.079    NA 390.9940     3
>  99: 2.454    NA 388.8896     3
> 100:    NA    NA 386.2610     3
>          a     b        c month
> ```

**EDIT**

The OP has disclosed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746566/replace-data-from-dataframe-using-other-threshold-table-in-r/53748026?noredirect=1#comment94365651_53748026) that he wants to run the solution on a huge dataframe with many columns.

The sequence of *non-equi update joins* can be executed in a loop as well:

```
threshold_cols <- c("a", "b")
setDT(df)
for(i in threshold_cols){
  df[thresholds, on = c("month", sprintf("%s<%s.min", i, i)), (i) := NA][
    thresholds, on = c("month", sprintf("%s>%s.max", i, i)), (i) := NA]
}
```

`df` is modified in place as shown above. There are *no* additional columns added. This is different to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747010/3817004) where `outcome` contains all the `a.min`, `a.max`, `b.min`, `b.max` columns merged from `thresholds`.

Comment: This is nice, but if there are more columns, then every column has to be dealt with in a new line. And I want to run this on a huge dataframe